# On the Definition of Conformality

Tags: complex-analysis

On [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Conformal_mapping), conformality is defined by saying that a continuous map $w=f(z)$ on a domain $\Omega$ is **conformal** at a point $z_0\in \Omega$ if given any two differentiable curves $a(t),b(t)$ that pass through $z_0$, then the oriented angle is preserved, in the sense that 
$$\arg \frac{d}{dt}f(a(t)) \Bigr|_{t=t_1} -\arg \frac{d}{dt}f(b(t)) \Bigr|_{t=t_2} = \arg a'(t_1)-\arg b'(t_2)$$
where $a(t_1)=z_0=b(t_2)$ and the limit
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}{\frac{|f(z)-f(z_0)|}{|z-z_0|}}$$ is finite.

However, what I fail to understand is the well-definedness of the above definition: we do not know that $f(a(t))$ or $f(b(t))$ are real-differentiable.  The obvious solution would be to require, where $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y),a(t)=x_1(t)+iy_1(t),b(t)=x_2(t)+iy_2(t)$, $u(x_k(t),y_k(t))$ and $v(x_k(t),y_k(t))$ to be real-differentiable for $k=1,2$.

But is this necessary? I.e. is there a better way to define the preservation of angles in such a way that this issues of $f$ being differentiable as a function of $t$ do not arise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many better definitions of conformality. For instance: Complex-differentiable at $z_0$ with nonzero derivative. The geometric meaning is that it preserves orientation of the tangent plane at $z_0$ and also preserves angles between tangent vectors at this point. For the geometric definition you would require also this function to be differentiable at $z_0$ as a function of two real variables.

Comment: I see, that confirms my suspicions.  For my purposes, I'd rather take the geometric definition since I'm trying to fill in their steps of showing it implies the complex differentiability at $z_0$ with non-zero derivative.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Possibly relevant: George Mark Bergman, *Angle preserving map* [comments on Problem 5084], **American Mathematical Monthly** 71 #2 & #7 (February & Aug.-Sept. 1964), [223](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2311779) & [803-804](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2310923). In particular, see the comment about Menchoff's 1926 Math. Annalen paper.